# Custom folding for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to get custom folding for sublime text 3, namely the markers:

```
*--#[
    some stuff
*--#]
```

indicate my region. I tried `AAAPacakgeDev`, but it doesn't seem to support folding. The package `SyntaxFold` introduces its own logic and new keybindings, which seems unnecessary.

It seems `.tmLanguage` does support folds, so what I did is I copied `Obective-C.tmLanguage` from its package to `Packages\FORM` and renamed it to `FORM.tmLanguage'. Then I modified the markers to:

```
<key>foldingStartMarker</key>
<string>^\*..#\[.*$</string>
<key>foldingStopMarker</key>
<string>^\*..#\].*$</string>
```

and changed the syntax to FORM. Even though the colors change and the pattern matches when I do a regex on the code, the folds are not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to [this](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/syntaxdefs.html) `foldingStartMarker` and `foldingStopMarker` are ignored. Folding seems to be in many cases indentation based, I added two more lines of stuff to your example code and sublime let me fold it while I was using a javascript file.

Comment: Yes. I found a ticket about this in the issue tracker so I am closing this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, this is a long-time [requested feature](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/101). I found the `SyntaxFold` package to be a convenient substitute. My configuration file looks like:

```
    {
        "endMarker": "^\\*..#\\][^\n]*$",
        "name": "Form",
        "startMarker": "^\\*..#\\[[^\n]*$"
    },
```

I also made the key bindings the same as the normal folds.