# Sublime Text 3 do not hide blocks of code

Tags: sublimetext3

I've been installing some packages when triangles (that are supposed to hide blocks of code) disappeared. How can I bring it back?

All installed packages:

- Emmet
- Gist
- BufferScroll
- ColorPicker
- Color Highlighter
- Package Controll

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Uninstall some packages? Check configuration of [some packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31898823/11683)?

Comment: Ok, I uninstalled all packages, it doesn't help. I thought there is some field in settings file that is responsible for it and someone will tell me about it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If you have the same issue, you sould just open 
*Preferences -> Settings* and set field `"fold_buttons" : true` in User Settings.

I accidently changed it when I was playing with Settings file just after installing Sublime Text 3 and then left it for several months.